# jQuery autocomplete; want Return key to behave as Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code behaves different when **tab** and **enter** keys are pressed:

--**tab** replaces the text field's value with the value of the selected item and focus goes to the next input box

--**enter** replaces the text field's value with the value of the selected item but the focus *does not* go to the next input box

How do I  change the behavior of **enter** so that the focus goes to the next input box?

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: ["test","some text"],
    delay: 0
});
```

I have tried to add the following line:

```
select: function(event, ui) { if (event.keyCode == 13) { trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 9 }); } }
```

This doesn't work. See http://jsfiddle.net/YbPVX/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: ["test","some text"],
    delay: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) { if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
       $(this).next("input").focus().select();
    } }
});
```

-> http://jsfiddle.net/YbPVX/5/

Comment: This only works for the later versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. Thanks!